# Is Concurrent Collection Needed Here?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm playing around with switching some code to using `Parallel.ForEach` and I have a question about whether I need to be concerned about the effects of concurrency here. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
public IList<Item> RetrieveAllItems(int paramValue)
{
    var itemFuncs = new List<Func<int, IEnumerable<Item>>>
                {
                    RetrieveItems1,//one method to retrieve items, taking an int param
                    RetrieveItems2//another one that takes an int param
                };

    List<Item> allItems = new List<Item>();

    Parallel.ForEach(itemFuncs, (f) =>
                {
                    //is this a problem?
                    allItems.AddRange(f(paramValue));
                });

    return allItems;
}
```

For this application, I do not care about the order that my `Item` objects are added to `allItems` (in fact, I do explicit ordering later on). My question is whether I could get into trouble here with both functions attempting to add `Item` objects at the same time.

My motivation for playing around with this is simply to try to speed up this sequence of events, and when I tried using a `BlockingCollection` instead, my timings, obviously slowed down to the point that there was hardly any difference between doing these two operations in parallel versus the old, serial way. When I use a simple `List<Item>` then I do see impressive speed-ups.

So, considering I am just adding objects to a collection in a parallel fashion, is using a non-thread safe collection asking for trouble here? My real-world experience with multi-threaded/parallel programming is very sparse, hence the uncertainty here.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, what you are doing is a problem. `List` is not thread-safe and adding items from multiple threads can lead to data corruption (for example individual elements overwriting each other).

You said that you don't care about the order of items inserted quickest fix is to use [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Another option is to the PLINQ extensions and use the [`Select` extension of the `ParallelQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The code would look like this:

```
return itemFuncs.AsParallel().SelectMany(f => f(paramValue)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips and answer. Another way of asking about this would have been for me to ask if adding items to a `List` is an atomic operation. Apparently, it isn't so that is good to know.

Comment: One correction, I'd need to use `itemFuncs.AsParallel().SelectMany(f => f(paramValue)).ToList();` otherwise I have a nested collection.

Comment: @ledbutter: Ah yes, I missed that, corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to return an `IEnumerable<Item>` you could simply enumerate to `List`s and then `Concat` the results.

Otherwise you could consider using a linked list, enumerating in parallel and then again `Concat`enating for O(1).

About the original question: yes, that code is dangerous and prone to race conditions